# Where to put custom/new class file in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, namespaces, yelp

I have PHP example on how to use Yelp Fusion API. It uses [`OAuth.php` file](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/blob/master/v2/php/lib/OAuth.php) with several classes. In main example it is imported with

```
require_once('lib/OAuth.php');
```

Can I do the same in Laravel?

Or I'd better provide namespace for `OAuth.php` file and put it somewhere on the tree? Where to put it?

Comment: is about test, that looks like a custom library, so just create a Library folder inside the app folder and place the class there with the right name space

Answer (score 3):

I suggest your to make a new directory inside app and call it like "Classes" and store your OAuth.php as "/app/Classes/OAuth.php".
Don't forget to put a `namespace App\Classes;` to top of this file.

Due to having several classes inside your file I suggest to rewrite this a bit and separate each class to file

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Yelp Fusion API with any OAuth implementation. To simplify the process and maintain a clean project, you can use an OAuth package.

You can find a list of OAuth packages for composer [here](https://packagist.org/search/?q=oauth.).

Using packages instead of custom PHP files would help to keep project clean.

If you do need to add any custom PHP files, it's recommended to create a directory within the `/app` directory for organization. A good directory name could be "Libraries" or "Helpers," depending on the type of content being stored.

Note that directories and files within the `/app` directory are automatically loaded by Composer.