# Where to put classes in a Laravel project

Tags: laravel

I have a coded years ago a custom PHP class to create and manage HTML tables.
I'd like to add it in my new Laravel project.
Where do you think it would be the best to put those files ?
Best regards,
Nicolas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to put custom/new class file in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277015/where-to-put-custom-new-class-file-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as you want. Laravel adopts the MVC architecture, if you see that your PHP class deals with databases put it Model folder (/App), if it's dealing with views, put it in views folder (/resources/views) and if it's a controller class you have to put it in controller (/App/Http/Controllers).

But the main thing you have to do is to read the Laravel documentation to understand really how it works. The link for the documentation is https://laravel.com/docs

Comment: Okay, I read the doc of course, but didn't find the part where they where talking about where to drop external classes...